# HazelCast multiCasting works inconsistently

Tags: hazelcast

I am using hazelCast to save only an integer value on 2 different java application. I have 2 java application which are running different servers. 
HazelCast connection is established successfully. When i try to increment the value using following command.

```
DistributedCounter counter = Hazelcast.getHazelcastInstanceByName("myinstance").getDistributedObject("myservice", "value");
counter.inc();
```

I am trying to get the value and to see value=10 after 10 increment operation is completed. but sometimes i have seen the value 8 or 9. sometimes it works.
inc method is :

```
NodeEngine nodeEngine = getNodeEngine();
  IncOperation operation = new IncOperation("value", 1);
  int partitionId = nodeEngine.getPartitionService().getPartitionId("value");
  InvocationBuilder builder = nodeEngine.getOperationService().createInvocationBuilder("myservice", operation, partitionId);
  try {
     final Future<Integer> future = builder.invoke();
     return true;
  } 
  catch (Exception e) {
     throw ExceptionUtil.rethrow(e);
  }
```

HazelCast network config is set as multiCasting. I disabled the tcp/ip.

Can anyone explain why hazelcast works inconsistently? And how can i come over this situation ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@OkayAtalay, I see that you created your own service. If you look to the example on Hazelcast Doc, http://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/3.10.2/manual/html-single/index.html#implementing-counterproxy, you'll see that `inc` operation wait for operation complete by calling `future.get()`. Even if you're just returning true/false, you must still wait for the operation to complete before sending another operation.

PS: Hazelcast already has `AtomicInteger` & `PN-Counter` dist. objects that do what you're doing manually here.

Comment: Thanks for answer. Actually,  I dont wanna wait while increment operation is work in progress. But in my code design, I must call incr method simultaneously. do you have any suggestion for my case?

Comment: it is hard to prepare a single application. how can i connect with you? may be linkedin

Comment: @OkayAtalay, you can share the link here or to our community gitter channel (https://gitter.im/hazelcast/hazelcast). In the meantime, I'll look to the service in our doc to simulate the behavior you're seeing.